# get hitTestPoint of two childs under same parent

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

i have a parent container:Background, in it there is arbitrary amount of fishes and fish foods object added as childs, and they have a hit box, how can i get the coordinate of thier collision when the fish and food collide? because i want to use the coordinate to do a effect. that is to draw a ripple.Is there a method to get the coordinate of when the two hitboxes in my Food and Fish symbol when they collide.

```
public function moveToFood():void
        {


            x -= (x - foodTarget.x) / 40;
            y -= (y - foodTarget.y) / 40;
            if (hit.hitTestObject(foodTarget.hit))
            {

                foodRipple.drawRipple(bg,bg.y, 10, 1);
                foodTarget.removeSelf();

            }
        }
```

Comment: It's easy to get the coordinate of the fish or the food; but what do you mean by the coordinate of their collision?

Comment: the food has a hitbox, the fish has a hitbox, i would like to get the point of contact between them when they touch each other.

Comment: Well say if hitbox **a** collides with the left-side of hitbox **b**. The point of contact could range anywhere along the height of the hitbox along the y axis.

Comment: What you could do is just get the point halfway between the centre of the fish and the food? Seems most logical to me.

Comment: Also I wouldn't be too concerned with getting the ripple exactly where the collision was. The ripple would be the result of removing an object that was afloat (food).

Comment: yes that is also a good way to do it,also is it possible for the parent container to know when a child is removed?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. For example, you could dispatch an event from the child when it's removed, and listen for it from the parent. You could call a function that belongs to the parent from the child when it's removed. Also you could have a removeElement() function in the parent that handles removing objects for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend taking a look at "Collision Detection Kit"
It may give you the pixel perfect collision point you are looking for.

http://code.google.com/p/collisiondetectionkit/

Answer (score 0):

Getting exact collision detection like you describe requires a library because Flash doesn't have that built-in. One way to get there is to use Box2D.